# Are body alteration questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious about a topic concerning implants, either medical or cosmetic. Would such questions be on topic here?

This is not for a specific treatment but for my self-education.

The question is like this (I'd formulate it more detailed when asked on the main site).

Currently when you have to power an implant (like a pace-maker) you either have a battery (which need changing) or have an constant open wound where the power plugs are. Why can't one implant a magnetic generator to recharge a battery by applying a rotating magnetic field?

Answer (score 3):

My initial impression would be that these questions be mostly on topic here, with the following conditions:

- questions cannot soliicit medical advice, so as not to violate the [rules](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of Bio.SE;
- questions should concern how the implanted device augments the human physiology;
- questions should concern how the implanted device is limited by chemical, phyisical or biological reasons;
- questions should be supported, as usual, by scientific fact, and not point to opninion-based websites describing the latest fad in implanted devices;
- should be not concern implants for the sake of discussing cosmetic reasons only.

If questions meet these criteria then they are probably a good fit for the site. For example, your example question about the electromagnetic design for a new pace-maker would fit (though you may not get a sufficient answer if the problem is strictly one of engineering).